# jquery - animate height to the new content's height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `div` with `height = 40 px`. I load inside it a html string which may have a random content's height.

I'm trying to animate my container's height to the new content's height (according to [jQuery animate height to auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209228/jquery-animate-height-to-auto)):

```
var jqObj = $('<div/>').html($.parseHTML(htmlString)).hide();

$('.mainCont').html(jqObj.html());
jqObj.fadeIn('slow');

var height = $('.mainCont').css('height', 'auto').height(); // get real height
$('.mainCont').animate({height: height+'px'}, 2000);
```

but I don't see any animation, only single jump to desired height. How to fix it ?

### edit

I see that `$('.mainCont').css('height', 'auto').height()` makes that situation. But without it I can't get the new content's height

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery can only animate numbers, but you're setting the style height to `auto` then you're trying to animate it to an integer, and jQuery doesn't know how to animate from the string `auto` as it means nothing.

Set the height to a number before animating

```
$('.mainCont').css('height', '0px').animate({height: height}, 2000);
```

I've set it to zero, I'm guessing you want something other than the number you're getting, otherwise you're animating from the current height to the current height, which means no movement.